# How can i add multiple modal boxes to an embedded svg file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Okay, so i've created a svg file that has 6 small boxes (Sciences, Human Sciences etc.)  and its on a website i've been working on. Now the issue is that all of the 6 boxes must have an individual modal box popup on onclick function to show a small description of iq. box. The svg has been done using Inkscape.  I have embedded the svg file inside `<object>` tag in to the html file.

```
<div id="content">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="paikkaKentallaEnglanniksi.svg"></object>
</div>
```

**Screenshot of the svg file on the website:**

[image]

Comment: Probably the moodal will be an html element whose content will change depending on the svg element you click. In order to receive help  please edit your question and add the code you have or a simplified version of it